# An exception occured while establishing a connection to figure out your platform version

Tags: prestashop

Trying to install PrestaShop through CLI but getting error

> An exception occured while establishing a connection to figure out
> your platform version. You can circumvent this by setting a
> 'server_version' configuration value
>
> For further information have a look at:
> https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/issues/673

Anyone has any idea where do I add the server_version config value?

Comment: This issue is also discussed here:  https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/issues/33524. At the end there an alternative solution is presented.

Answer (score 3):

You should set server_version to your database server version (that depends on your hosting provider).

In your PrestaShop/app/config/config.yml there should be a "doctrine" section.

Beware that config is in `yaml` format and is case-sensitive and whitespace-sensitive. You should use the exact same indentations.

```yml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: xxx
        connections:
            xxx:
                server_version:
```

If you don't know your database version, and using `mysql`, nowadays, "8.0" is a safe first guess.

Comment: Thanks its working for me in symfony2

Comment: Thanks it worked. But in my case it was in this file: app/config/doctrine.yml